# SQL Grouping GPS Trip Data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

this is my Table
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e5001/1)

I need to create this report

[image: Report]

the Driving Flag is the status of the car
so i need the first point of the true (driving) as the trip start
the last point as the end with total period and total distance

the same with the stop 
and the max and avg speed for the movment
The Table Should be ordered by id to keep the driving record in order
Thank You

Edit

```
    SELECT        
    carid
    , (SUM(CASE WHEN speed < 3 THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(minute, b.trackold, b.TrackTime) END)) AS speeding
    , (SUM(CASE WHEN speed >= 3 THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(minute, b.trackold, b.TrackTime) END)) AS parked
    , round(sum(Distance / 1000), 2) AS Distance
    , TrackDay 
FROM            
(
    SELECT        
        carid
        , TrackDay
        , TrackTime
        , trackold
        , speed
        , TrackDayOld
        , diff
        , Distance  
    FROM            
    (
        SELECT        
            carid
            , TrackTime
            , LAG(TrackTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY carid ORDER BY TrackTime) AS trackold
            , CONVERT(date, TrackTime) AS TrackDay
            , CONVERT(date, LAG(TrackTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY carid  ORDER BY TrackTime)) AS TrackDayOld
            , speed
            , datediff(minute, LAG(TrackTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY carid ORDER BY carid), TrackTime) AS diff
            , Distance 
        FROM T_Tracking
    ) a 
    WHERE a.TrackDay = a.TrackDayOld
) b GROUP BY carid
    , TrackDay
```

this is my last try (Before creating Drive Flag Based on speed)`
but it group by the whole day(get total )

Comment: By IMEi and Driving (i.e Moving for 30Min with 10 KM Distance, Stopped for 30Min ) get period(LastDate-StartDate) and get Total distance

Comment: i Have Added My last Query in the main post

Comment: I could be wrong but in sample data as the Id increments the TrackTime and CurrTime go backwards for IMEI 860990002931419 for example. Is this expected?

Comment: this is sample data the true data is correct i.e id=100 , time 10:00 , id=101 time=10:02,id=102 time=10:03 this happens when copy data to fiddle

Comment: If you could be so kind to correct the sample data that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: OK first data is fixed second you should use TrackTime for order not the id since the device can send multibe records at the same time

Comment: So is the first Driving = false for each IMEI the stop record?

Comment: yes drive false mean stop your question why speed>0 because i manualy added the drive flag for test

Comment: Given the sample data, what is your desired result?

Comment: the desired result is the report shown in the image i.e Car1 start moving at 10:15 am stoped at 11:25 am drive time for that trip 1:10 - 120km max speed :100 min speed:10 avg speed :40